# How to set different routes for the same Controller method with different parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I have the ReportController that llooks like this:

```
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId){
    ....
}
```

and

```
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId, bool ? approved) {
    ....
}
```

and I tried to do some routing, bu it failed. Actual code written in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "ReportDetailsValidation",
                    template: "descriptionValidation",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Report", action = "ReportDetails", reportId ="{reportId}", approved = "{approved}" }
                    );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "ReportDetails",
                    template: "description",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Report", action = "ReportDetails"} 
                    );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

As I have seen I need to match the following URL's:
**/Report/ReportDetails?reportId=7** for the first and
**/Report/ReportDetails?reportId=7&approved=True** for second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, like have 2 methods with identical name with different parameters, because you should get **AmbiguousActionException**.

ASP Core Action Selector does not care about Action's parameters during select action. Therefore you can't have 2 actions correspond one route template. The only workaround is to play with action constraints (like HttpGet and HttpPost).
You can [check it yourself on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c27b07ef3f8b07dfe1d1de38a8d7bf2d6a9298f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ActionSelector.cs). (See **SelectBestCandidate** method)

Theoretically if parameters matters the logic to choose between actions based on parameters should be in **SelectBestActions** method, but it ignores parameters.

In you case good option seems to be to have just 1 method:

```
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId, bool? approved) {
    ....
}
```

and then check if approved is NULL (**/Report/ReportDetails?reportId=7**), then implement 1st logic, otherwise(**/Report/ReportDetails?reportId=7&approved=True**) implement 2nd logic. If logic contains many lines you can extract them in new method and call it.

```
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId, bool? approved) {
     if (approved != null)
     {
        //implement logic for 2nd case(approved=True)
     }
     //implement logic for 1st case (just reportId=7)
}
```

Comment: In the standard case you will get the mentioned exception, but it's no problem at all to have multiple methods with identical names. You just have to help the selection process along by using `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`s (see my answer). But in the specific case presented here, you are right there is no need to and it is easier to use a default parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) to understand routing

```
[HttpGet("Report/ReportDetails/{reportId}")] 
[HttpGet("Report/ReportDetails/{reportId}/{approved}")]
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId, bool? approved) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use RouteAttribute

```
[Route("ReportDetails/{reportId}")]
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId){
....
[Route("ReportDetails/{reportId}/{approved}")]
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId, bool ? approved) {
....
```

Your URLs would then be;

/Report/ReportDetails/7 for the first and

/Report/ReportDetails/7/True for second

This will work with the default startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this but as I mentioned my links are the one that I specified. I used in the views @Html.ActionLinkFor (I don`t understand why it makes the url's without "/" after view name). I would have wanted the links to be the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`. In your controller you can add your attribute to both methods to enable matching the correct method to the URL.

You could for example make a `ParameterExistsAttribute` that decides if the method is suitable and then use

```
[ParameterExists('approved', false)]
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId){
    ....
}

[ParameterExists('approved', true)]
public IActionResult ReportDetails(int? reportId, bool ? approved) {
    ....
}
```

The puzzle on how to implement such an attribute remains an exercise to the reader. (It's not so difficult.)

As an example here's an attribute that selects an API call, based on the value of a parameter.

```
public class FormPostFilterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
  private readonly string _elementId;
  private readonly string _requiredValue;

  public FormPostFilterAttribute(string elementId, string requiredValue)
  {
    _elementId = elementId;
    _requiredValue = requiredValue;
  }

  public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[_elementId]))
    {
      return false;
    }

    return (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[_elementId] == _requiredValue);
  }
}
```